# iframe with document.write

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I need to insert the ad code with the document.write. But it overwrites the entire page.
The script has the following form:

```
<script>
document.write.// some code
</script>
```

Tell me, please, how best to insert it? I think to use iframe, but maybe there are better methods. It possible to write it inside the iframe, like: `<iframe><script>somecode</script></iframe>`? We use AdFox, so the script should be without any libraries.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `document.body.innerHTML += '<!-- ENTER CODE HERE -->';` to append to the bottom of your site

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` overwrites everything after the page has loaded (after the document is ready). The best solution would probably depend on the nature of the ad. If it is very simple (e.g. a single image), try [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) To make elements and then add them to parent elements with [Parent.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

If the ad is more complex, do you have a given "parent node" where all your code can be added? If so, simply do `parent.innerHTML = your_html_code`.

Also, iframes do not work that way. They do not allow you to insert any random code by placing it inside the iframe tags. In fact, the content inside tags only show when the browser **does not support the element**. You have to have a source url from which to do it. For reference, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: If you did `parent.innerHTML = your_html_code` everything in the `parent` would be removed. `parent.innerHTML += your_html_code` would append it

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, but I am assuming the space would be specially allotted like a <div class=“ad-container”></div>, but I do not have experience with writing ads, so it’s all assumptions

Comment: The problem is that the code not only displays some elements, but is part of the script. I can not explain in words, so I downloaded the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPELQy